# ¿Como evitar que se vulevan a mostrar los DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Cuando recargo la pantalla principal, los DialogFragment que anteriormente habían sido mostrados con show vuelven a mostrarse. Sin embargo, tengo unos procesos que se ejecutan con el evento onDismiss y pareciera ser que el dismiss si se está ejecutando cuando el dialog pierde el foco. Segun había entendido el proceso de dismiss destruye el dialog, pero al parecer se acumulan ya que al salir del programa y volver a entrar, se muestran todos los dialog que he creado provocando que se acumulen

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

en un spinner selcciono un item y el evento crea el dialogo y por medio del bundle le envío el valor del item

```
spinOrders.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String docNum = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if(!docNum.equals("")){
                currentDoc = docNum;
                btnRotulos.setEnabled(false);
                lTagsToShow.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                QRDialog = OrderSapQrDialog.newInstance(docNum);
                QRDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "QRDocNum");
                textLabel.setText("");

                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                QRDialog.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        getDocumentList();
                        onResume();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
```

El código de mi dialogo es el siguiente

```
public class OrderSapQrDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public final static int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    public final static int BLACK = 0xFF000000;
    public final static int WIDTH = 400;
    public final static int HEIGHT = 400;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final String docNum = getArguments().getString("DocNum");
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_order_sap_qr, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = root.findViewById(R.id.imageQRDocNum);
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(docNum);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return root;
    }

    static public OrderSapQrDialog newInstance(String strArg) {
        OrderSapQrDialog f = new OrderSapQrDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("DocNum", strArg);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws WriterException {
        BitMatrix result;
        try {
            result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            return null;
        }

        int width = result.getWidth();
        int height = result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;
    }


}
```

Dejo un gif del comportamiento que me esta dando problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de estar haciendo varias pruebas se solucionó de una manera que no esperaba.

```
spinOrders.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        String docNum = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if(!docNum.equals("")){
            currentDoc = docNum;
            btnRotulos.setEnabled(false);
            lTagsToShow.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            QRDialog = OrderSapQrDialog.newInstance(docNum);
            QRDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "QRDocNum");
            textLabel.setText("");

            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            QRDialog.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    QRDialog.dismiss(); // instrucción faltante
                    getDocumentList();
                    onResume();
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Al parecer getDialog().setOnDismissListener agrega el listener del Dismiss al objeto android.app.Dialog el cual es independiente a DialogFragment, por lo que al escuchar el onDismiss del android.app.Dialog, dentro se tiene que invocar el dismiss del DialogFragment para que sea descartado por completo.

Es interesante este detalle porque al momento de estar ejecutando el dismiss del app.Dialog, el comportamiento de la interfaz pareciera ser que en verdad esta descartando el DialogFragment cuando solo descarta el dialog que se está controlando (android.app.Dialog)